# Vertical line missing in a cell missing

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I try to draw a diagonal line in the first cell in the table below, using Tikz. But the vertical border at its left is missing. How could I fix it? 
The code is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{makecell}

\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\rule[-2.5mm]{0pt}{5.5mm}%
                     \centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand\diag[4]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{p{#2}|}{\hskip-\tabcolsep
  $\vcenter{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0,anchor=south west,inner sep=#1]
  \path[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (#2+2\tabcolsep,\baselineskip);
  \node[minimum width={#2+2\tabcolsep-\pgflinewidth},
        minimum  height=\baselineskip+\extrarowheight-\pgflinewidth] (box) {};
  \draw[line cap=round] (box.north west) -- (box.south east);
  \node[anchor=south west] at (box.south west) {#3};
  \node[anchor=north east] at (box.north east) {#4};
 \end{tikzpicture}}$\hskip-\tabcolsep}}

    \begin{document}

    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0.2cm}
    \begin{tabular}{|x{0.5cm}|x{0.5cm}|x{0.5cm}|x{0.5cm}|x{0.5cm}|}\hline
    \diag{.1em}{.5cm}{$X$}{$Y$}&12&18&50&16\\ \hline
    &&&&20\\ \hline
    &&&&30\\ \hline
    &&&&45\\ \hline
    15&12&18&50&32\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \end{document}
```

and the output is:

[image]

EDIT: I used the code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tbp]
 \begin{center}
  \setcellgapes{5pt} \makegapedcells \setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}
  \begin{tabular}{|x{0.5cm}|x{0.5cm}|x{0.5cm}|x{0.5cm}|x{0.5cm}|}\hline
        \diaghead(-1,1){XX}{$X$}{$Y$}   & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\ \hline
        0 & $\frac{1}{20}$ & $\frac{2}{20}$ & $\frac{1}{20}$ & $\frac{1}{20}$\\ \hline
        1 & $\frac{2}{20}$ & $\frac{3}{20}$ & $0$&$\frac{1}{20}$\\ \hline
        2 & $\frac{3}{20}$ & $0$ & $\frac{4}{20}$ & $\frac{2}{20}$\\ \hline
   \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

How can I adjust the diagonal line to link properly the corners in the first cell?

Comment: `\newcommand\diag[4]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{|p{#2}|}{...` should help. Notice the additional `|` right before `p{#2}`.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 4.0), you can draw the tabular as you have done and you have a command `\diagbox` (available only in the environments of `nicematrix`) which draws what is asked in the question. Moreover, you can simplify the code by using the key `hvlines` which draws all the rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2mm}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[columns-width=5mm,hvlines]
\diagbox{$X$}{$Y$}&12&18&50&16\\ 
&&&&20\\ 
&&&&30\\ 
&&&&45\\ 
15&12&18&50&32
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

If you want to center vertically the contents of the cells, all the techniques of `{tabular}` of `array` are available. Maybe the easier is to add a strut with a `\rule`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2mm}
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\rule[-2.5mm]{0pt}{5.5mm}}ccccc}[columns-width=5mm,hvlines]
\diagbox{$X$}{$Y$}&12&18&50&16\\ 
&&&&20\\ 
&&&&30\\ 
&&&&45\\ 
15&12&18&50&32
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the second MWE]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With your solution, how could the text in the cells be centered vertically?

Comment: All the usual technics are available. I have modified my answer to present a method.

Comment: Amazing! I must have missed `NiceTabular` when glancing through the manual....

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat: `NiceTabular` is very recent: in v4.0, 2020/05/08 and in fact, in that version, the command `\diagbox` was present but not documented. It is documented in v4.1, 2020/05/27. The documentation of that version has been changed to insist more on `NiceTabular`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I used the command you suggested in the first solution by @leandriis, since I have some problems when trying to install nicematrix.sty. I don't know how to adjust now the diagonal line in the first cell to link properly the corners. The output is in the edited question.

Comment: I extracted from the archive here https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix, the nicematrix.sty using the .ins file, in the current folder. With XeLatex the following error occurs:...rror:nn { nicematrix } {  exp13-too-old } } . I would really appreciate if you could tell how to fix this.

Comment: You should update thoroughly your TeX installation. Depending of your TeX distribution (TeXLive, MikTeX, MacTeX,...), the method is different. Concerning TeXLive, TeXLive 2020, released in April, will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

With `\multicolumn{1}...` you can not only overwrite the horizontal alignment of a cell but also remove/add vertical lines on either side of that cell.

In your original definition of the `\diag` command, you used `\multicolumn{1}{p{#2}|}` which adds a vertical line at the right of the cell. Change this to `\multicolumn{1}{|p{#2}|}` with an additional `|` right before the `p...`.  in order to also get the vertical line on the eft of the cell.

Comment: It works well. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Is there any solution to center vertically the text in the cells?

Answer (score 1):

Since you load `makecell` I would use its macro`\diaghead`:

> This package offers macro based on possibilities of picture
>   environment.

```
\diaghead(<H ratio,V ratioi>){<Text set for column
> width>}% {<First head>}{<Second head>}
```

> where () sets the ratios like in \line command
>   (digits from 1 up to 6). This argument is optional, the default ratio
>   (\line direction) defined (5,-2).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \setcellgapes{5pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|x{0.5cm}|x{0.5cm}|x{0.5cm}|x{0.5cm}|x{0.5cm}|}\hline
\diaghead(-1,1){XX}{$Y$}{$X$}   & 12 & 18 & 50 & 16 \\ \hline
                                &    &    &    & 20 \\ \hline
                                &    &    &    & 30 \\ \hline
                                &    &    &    & 45 \\ \hline
                            15  &12  & 18 & 50 & 32 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It is all right.

Comment: @Cris, content of cells are centered to see this instead numbers  insert letters "abg".  Since numbers haven't depth as have letters g,q,y, it seems that the space above them is smaller than below. This depth you can compensate with adding `\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}` after `makegapedcellgape` in table code.

Comment: I still have a problem with the diagonal line in the first cell. I think this is because the number ol columns and of the rows are different. I used your code and the new output is in the question. I didn't work too much with tables.

Comment: @Cris, you are right, `extrarowheight` is not the solution. With my answer is not possible better vertical centering as already achieved.